# Visual Studio Community 2015 - Unity IntelliSense not showing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Unity with Visual Studio 2015 Community as editor. I added a new script and double clicked it which opened Visual Studio. But when I now type in something like gameObject or something else which is Unity specified, no IntelliSense is showing up.

How to fix that?

Comment: Check the answer in the duplicated question. There are many things that could cause this problem and also many possible solution.

Comment: "1.From Visual Studio, go to Tools --> Options... --> Tools for Unity --> Miscellaneous. Under Show connectivity icon, set it to true then restart Visual Studio." was the solution for my problem. Thanks @Programmer for the link :)

Comment: Nice. Even the first solution fixed it.